# Meaning of the phrasal verb "divert from"

Tags: meaning, verbs, meaning-in-context

In this sentence here, do you think *diverted from* means *distracted from* or *change of course*? The second option doesn't seem to make much sense, though.

> “When the imperial mantle finally falls on the shoulders of Louis Bonaparte,” Marx predicted in 1852, “the bronze statue of Napoleon will crash from the top of the Vendôme Column.” On May 16, 1871, the hated symbol collapsed before a Communard crowd, temporarily **diverted from** the threatening gunfire of the forces of reaction encircling Paris. Between the prediction and the event lay eighteen years of “ferocious farce.” - *Paris, Capital of Modernity*

Comment: ...... distracted from

Comment: Or, "crowd, whose attention was momentarily diverted from the threatening gunfire . . .."

Comment: Id argue that this is a verb + prepositional phrase usage.

Answer (score 1):

As rhetorician mentioned, *the crowd* (or, rather their attention) was diverted, not the statue. They were temporarily distracted by the sight and sound of the statue crashing to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

> the bronze statue of Napoleon will crash from the top of the Vendôme Column.

So the statue is the "symbol" referred to in the following sentence:

> the hated symbol collapsed before a Communard crowd, temporarily diverted from the threatening gunfire of the forces of reaction encircling Paris

And it pretty clearly states that the symbol, being the statue, was diverted from the gunfire (by collapsing below the line of sight of the gunfire presumably), so I would interpret this literally and a physical object being physically "diverted" out of the course of gunfire.

Unless there is some subtle rhetoric I am missing...

Comment: It was the crowd that had been diverted.

Answer (score -2):

it means to sort of avoid the gunfire

Comment: Sort of, but not really